# Moving Obstacle

Tags: ros, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test my local planner for moving obstacles. How can I simulate moving obstacles to test the code ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232676/moving-obstacle/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-04-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VEGETA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26893/vegeta/) on 2016-05-28**:
hi there friend, can you give me a link for the package you used to detect dynamic obstacles?

**Comment by [VEGETA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26893/vegeta/) on 2016-05-28**:
my email: hossam.moghrabi@gmail.com
or in #ros@irc.freenode.com by the nick [VEGETA]

**Comment by [chensiyuan0214](https://answers.ros.org/users/37451/chensiyuan0214/) on 2018-11-11**:
Hi there, could you please give me a link for the package you used to detect dynamic obstacles?
My email is: chensiyuan0214@hotmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using Gazebo, maybe you can look this link : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=animated_box

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1